# Tinymce mceInsertContent joins all the closing followed tags at the end

Tags: html, tinymce

I am using mceInsertContent to insert external text in Tinymce editor.
This text requires tags (eg `<tag>text</tag>`), because later need to search for this tags...
The problem happens when the insertion it's sequential.

A generic exemple it's clicking 3 times in:

```
<button onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<tag>text</tag>');">
```

then view the html genereted in editor:

Expected result:

```
<tag>text</tag><tag>text</tag><tag>text</tag>
```

Actual result:

```
<tag>text<tag>text<tag>text</tag></tag></tag>
```

Is there any way to disable this conversion?

even positioning the cursor elsewhere (between clicks) and returning to the front of the insertion... don't work.

Comment: resolution [link](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5188)

Comment: +1, thx to your solution. i suggest you post it here as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2):

You can add '\uFEFF' to the end of your text.

`<button onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<tag>text</tag>\uFEFF');">`

I've tested this solution in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    text ');">
```

Use Space character   at the end of HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can add (&nbsp) space character to the end of your html.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with  tags and mceInsertContent. What was happening in my case is I am inserting content enclosed in a span tag and after it was inserted, the span stayed open even though I could see the closing span tag. Adding the '\uFEFF' string at the end worked however I had to combine the whole element into a single call.
Prior to that I had a few mceInsertContent commands in a row to build the element and adding the \uFEFF to the end didn't work there until I combined everything into one line.

```
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "<span class=\'ima\' style=\'color:blue\'>");
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "<-");
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "UNKNOWN (" + curPos + ")");
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "->");
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "</span>\uFEFF");
```

Didn't work but:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "<span class=\'ima\' style=\'color:blue\'><-UNKNOWN (" + curPos + ")-></span>\uFEFF");
```

worked